# How to merge multiple files into one?

Tags: c#

I wrote a code that should read all the files in the directory and save to one. Well, for some reason it only reads one file.

```
 foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*"))
        {
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllText(file))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"D:\ee.txt", line.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: The [File.WriteAllText documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-6.0) says _Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten._ . Note the last sentence.

Comment: [File.AppendText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-6.0) is probably what you need. Always read the docs.

Comment: File.AppendText yes it helped, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of finding the files in a Directory and merging the content into 1 new file is explained here.

```
string contents = string.Empty;
string[] arr = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Jay", "*.txt");
foreach (string file in arr)
{
   contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
   File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Jay\mergedfile.txt", contents, Encoding.Default);
}
```